# (Nuxt.js) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: apache, ssl, nuxt.js, reverse-proxy

My problem is the following:

I have a Nuxt.js app on my server. SSL and reverse-proxy is all configured (Apache).
When i build and start the app (SSR rendering) and visit `http://mydomain.name:3000`, everything works fine.

But visiting `https://mydomain.name` gives me tons of errors, like these:

`GET https://mydomain.name 404 (Not Found)`,
`(5) GET https://mydomain.name/_nuxt/vendors/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`,
And so on...

Already tried to configure the nuxt.config.js file with no luck:

```
server: {
  host: "0.0.0.0",
  port: 3000
},
build: {
  publicPath: "https://mydomain.name"
},
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Try setting your port in your `nuxt.config.js` to 80, which is the default port for accessing a page with http. You also probably shouldn't set your `publicPath`. If you don't know what it does, you likely won't need it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.